# javascript array index problem!

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

var a = new array();
    a[1] = 'A';
    b[10] = 'B';
    console.log(a);
    /*[undefined, "A", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
      undefined, undefined, "B"]*/
I want to remove undefined element
but what is the process??

Comment: var a = new Array(); a[1] = 'A'; a[10] = 'B'; console.log(a);  [empty, "A", empty × 8, "B"]  to be up to date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, jQuery has nothing to do with this.

Second, arrays are "autofilled". If you define index `10`, all indexes `0` - `9` will be occupied automatically, that's just the way Javascript arrays work.

What you're looking for is probably an object:

```
var a = {};
a[1] = 'A';
a[10] = 'B';
```

or

```
var a = {
    1 : 'A',
    10 : 'B'
};
```

Comment: but i have need a list of value

Answer (score 1):

well, to remove those `undefined` parts do

```
a[0] = 'A';
a[1] = 'B';
```

In your snippet, you fill the element with index `10` which forces the ECMAscript to create an array with `10 fields`. There are no definitions for all that fields between `1` and `10`, which means those are correctly `undefined`.

To remove that fields you either have to set a proper value or `map` the `non-undefined` values into a new array which would just be unnecesarry if you create a correct array in the first place.

Create an true `object` instead of an array (which actually also is an object) to have your desired behavior.

```
var a = {};

a[1] = 'A';
a[2] = 'B';

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use an `Object` instead of an `Array` like so:

```
var a = {}; // or var a = new Object();
a[1] = 'A';
a[10] = 'B';
a['foo'] = 'bar';
a.bar = 'foo'; // same as a['bar'] = 'foo';
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays always start at 0 and then go up to the last filled index.
You could use an object to solve your problem:

```
var a = {};
a[1] = 'A';
a[10] = 'B';
```